# Android app not scaling properly for small devices

Tags: android, android-xml, android-cardview

I am making an android app where a certain layout is not scaling properly.The cardviews are clashing over each, I know it is because of the hardcoded pixels but if I don't do that how can I achieve this type of output.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout            
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/culinary"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="144dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/culinary" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/music"
            android:layout_width="161dp"
            android:layout_height="146dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView25"
                android:layout_width="143dp"
                android:layout_height="133dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/music" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/literature"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/culinary"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView26"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/literature" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/acting"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photography"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.072">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/drama" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/design"
            android:layout_width="122dp"
            android:layout_height="122dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/music"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.009">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                android:layout_width="114dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/fashion" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/handicrafts"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="122dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.974"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photography"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/handicraft" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/drawing"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photography"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.225">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/drawing2" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/photography"
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/handicrafts"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.034">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/photography1" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/miscellanous"
            android:layout_width="77dp"
            android:layout_height="124dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/acting"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.222"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/drawing"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photography"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.083">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/misc" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the desired output and the ouput im getting:
[image: Output Im getting]

[image: Desired Output]

Please help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're new to android I suggest starting with simpler layouts because ConstraintLayout is kinda tricky. It's trying to be everything at once which makes it complicated to use. Try LinearLayout instead. I tried to edit your layout and here's what I got.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="146dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/culinary"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
                app:cardElevation="20dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView23"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/culinary" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/music"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
                app:cardElevation="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView25"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/music" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/literature"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
                app:cardElevation="20dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView26"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/literature" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/acting"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
                app:cardElevation="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/drama" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/design"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
                app:cardElevation="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                    android:layout_width="114dp"
                    android:layout_height="105dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fashion" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/handicrafts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="122dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
            app:cardElevation="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/handicraft" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/drawing"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
                app:cardElevation="20dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/drawing2" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/photography"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
                app:cardElevation="20dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/photography1" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/miscellanous"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
                app:cardElevation="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/misc" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hey Egis, for your time and effort with this answer you got my upvote. But please notice that you are using hardcoded sizes like `android:layout_height="165dp"` and this will make your layout to be non-responsive. Check my answer below that talks about this subject.

Comment: I just wanted to show how LinearLayout can be used in this case. I'm not nitpicking everything to make it perfect. I agree with your point about hardocded sizes, though.

Answer (score 3):

In Android, you need to consider the number of different screen sizes when developing an android application.

**Different phones got different screen size**, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view (fixed size is `50dp` for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

To solve your problem I would recommend using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to suport different screen sizes.

**Here is an example of a layout that looks the same as you want:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio=""
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="9"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="7"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]

Comment: As you can see in the XML code, I am using a Constraint Layout.

Comment: I am well aware, but consider using it with Guidelines/chains to replace your fixed sized and thus fit al screen sizes